# Datetime prebuilt enity issue with LUIS

Tags: entity, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

In LUIS I am having issue with assign prebuilt datetime entity. I have to take care the user queries like 'between dd/mm/yyyy and dd1/mm1/yyyy1'. It is not recognising the second date properly.

Answer (score 0):

LUIS is definitely not perfect and this is an internal problem so you can't change the behavior yourself. You'll have to create a work-around.

If you are expecting the user to fill in two dates and you only get one back I would suggest creating a substring of your original query and running it again. Since the EndIndex is included in the first result, this shouldn't be hard to do.

If the second query returns a date then there are two dates. If it doesn't then no range was specified.

Note: I tested this myself and found out that when you leave out the "and" and just query something like "between dd-MM-yyyy dd1-MM1-yyyy1" both dates get recognized.

Warning: Do check if your dates are parsed correctly. If you have an English LUIS application the default date format is MM-dd-yyyy. If you send your queries in the  dd-MM-yyyy format your day and month will get switched around.

Comment: Xeno-D Thanks for the reply. Yes i am using English LUIS,and one issue is with date format (dd/MM/YYYY) didnt work. Also I am passing the date as '12/26/2016' which LUIS is not able to recognize when i pass the date like 'dec 26 2016' it recognise it.

Comment: Yes It's troublesome but nothing you can do about it since it is a prebuilt entity. You'll have to use a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Improvements to the prebuilt datetime entities have been released for the English culture in LUIS. However, because of this the improved entity has been released as a separate entity to avoid breaking applications using the old datetime.

One of the improvements addresses this scenario specifically, date range recognition. You can find a blog post that goes into detail on the improvements [**here**](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/08/Luis-Date-Time-Entities/).

Here's a capture of what the new prebuilt looks like when adding it to your LUIS app.

[image]